# JBPM 5.4 - suspend/hold a Human-Task

Tags: jbpm

I have requirement to let the user '**hold**' the case/process-instance with him.
I can compare the hold state to the 'Suspended' state of Human-Task life-cycle.

The **TaskClient.suspend()** just takes the task-id and transfers it's state.

But I need to update the task form date as well.

I am not sure of how to do this.

I am planning to explicity call **TaskClient.setDocumentContent()** and save the data and then call **TaskClient.suspend().**

Is it a correct approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, can you clarify what will happen with the task on hold? Forms and tasks are separated components in jbpm. If you take a look at the jbpm console ng, the task is in a frozen state while it is in a different state than in progress, so if you change the state to another it will froze the form.
Does that work for you?